# Introducing "patterns" to the bar plots which already has a x-axis, y-axis and fill outlined. Can I show 4 categorical variables in a bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, categorical-data

Can we introduce 4 different categoricals in a bar plot? This is my code:

```
sur %>%
  drop_na(circumstances_bite) %>% # Dropping the NA columns
  count(circumstances_bite, circumstances_bite_broad) %>% 
  arrange(circumstances_bite_broad, desc(n)) %>% 
  mutate(circumstances_bite = fct_inorder(circumstances_bite))  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = circumstances_bite, fill = circumstances_bite_broad)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab("No of people") +
  ylab("circumstance of bite") +
  ggtitle("Overall circumstances of bite")+
  geom_text(aes(label = n), hjust = -0.2) +  # adding values for the bar
  facet_wrap(~circumstances_bite_broad, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") + 
  guides(fill = FALSE)+ # removing the legend 
scale_fill_manual( values =c ("Intentional Human Engagement" = "red" ,
                      "Unintentional Human Engagement" = "blue" , 
                      "Apparently unprovoked" = "magenta"))
```

The plot derived is attached in this question.

I have another variable that categorises the "Intentional Human Engagement" into 3 further categorical variables. How do I introduce this in the graph? If there was a way to show patterns (dots, line or crossess) within the bar graph to show this, that would fix it. How do I do this?

[image: img]

I do not know if it is possible to use patterns in the bar graph. Also, the x-axis, y-axis and fill is already outlined. Is there a way to show the 4th variable?

Comment: The ggpattern package can do this. But you’re currently faceting by and mapping `fill` to the same variable; why not facet by one variable and `fill` by the other, probably with `position = "dodge"`? Another option might be to facet by multiple variables, using either `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()`.